# What would be the best way to make a canvas element fall without a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that has a function called bird. basically all it does is creates an arc in canvas. What I want is to have another function that takes this arc and causes it to fall without using a constructor function. I am trying to understand movements in canvas and I hope this is a very basic type of movement.

```
x = 25;
y = 300;

function bird() {
    canvas;
    ctx;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Basic canvas animation

To animate you need to redraw the objects we are animating many times a second.

#### Render function

So we create a function that draws something, we add arguments to this function that describe that part we want to change over time.

```
function drawBall(x,y){  // the x and y position of a ball
    ctx.beginPath(); // start a new shape
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI *2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

We need to call the above function many times a second, redrawing at a slightly different position each frame (frame is what we call one image in the animation)

#### Frames

For the browser there is a special function specifically designed to run a function that draws a frame that is synced up to the display hardware and give smooth animation. `requestAnimationFrame`

requestAnimationFrame is given a referance to a function that it calls when the browser is ready to draw a frame. In that function we do everything we need to update the frame.

```
var ballX = 100;  // the start position of the ball
var ballY = 20;
requestAnimationFrame(update); // ask for a frame
function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height); // clears the canvas
    ballY += 2; // move the ball position down a little
    // now call the function that draws the ball
    drawBall(ballX,ballY);
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // ask for the next frame
}
```

And that is how to animate at the most basic level.

The above code is dumb and even when the ball is passed the bottom of the canvas it will still keep going. You may want the ball to stop at some point or bounce, and when something falls each moment in time it goes a little bit faster due to the pull of gravity.

#### Ball falling with bounce.

This can all be done using the same code structure as above but with a little more logic and some more variables. The demo below shows a very basic ball bouncing.

```js
// set up the canvas
const canvas = myCanvas; // ge the canvas element by its unique id
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get a 2d drawing context

// function to draw the ball
function drawBall(x,y,radius){  // the x and y position of a ball
    ctx.beginPath(); // start a new drawing
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI *2);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var ballX = 100;  // the start position of the ball
var ballY = 20;
// speed of the ball in the x amd y directions
var ballXSpeed = 0; // start speed is zero
var ballYSpeed = 0; // start speed is zero
var ballRadius = 10;
const gravity = 0.2; // strength of gravity
requestAnimationFrame(update); // ask for a frame
function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clears the canvas
    ballYSpeed += gravity; // increase the ball speed down by the force of gravity    
    ballY += ballYSpeed; // move the ball
    ballX += ballXSpeed; // move the ball
    // Now check if the ball posistion is such that it is touching the
    // bottom of the canvas. This is not a perfect bounce as it 
    // does not bother with the fact that over the time since the last frame
    // the ball hit the bottom at some time between, we dont calculate when.
    // Because of this the ball losses a little energy each bounce.
    if(ballY + ballRadius >= canvas.height){
        ballY = canvas.height - ballRadius; // position the ball touching the bottom
        ballYSpeed = -ballYSpeed; // reverse the ball direction
    }
    // now call the function that draws the ball
    drawBall(ballX,ballY,ballRadius);
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // ask for the next frame
}
```

```css
canvas {
   border : 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=myCanvas width=500 height=200></canvas>
```